# weekly spend formula in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anyone help please?
I have a spreadsheet where A:A contains dates and B:B shows the amount i spent on that day in relation to the date in A:A.
What i would like to do is have C1 show a running total of what i have spent this week.

I am using Excel 2007 and i cannot get my head around this.

I am going round in circles here, i can get =SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(A2:A1000)=5)*(B2:B1000)) which shows how much has been spent on a thursday, justcannot work out how to say for the last week

Comment: Thursday of last week or all of last week? How do you define a 'week'; Sunday to Saturday?

Comment: better to go for vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it simpler.

Add a column before the DATE column and call it WEEK

In A2 use (x should be 1 , 2 depending on the system for your country)

```
=Year(B2)&WeekNum(B2,x)
```

> 1 = week start sunday
>   2 = week start monday

then in D2 use ( and drag it down the column)

```
=SUMIF(A$2:A2,A2,C$2:C2)
```

Comment: That is awesome thankyou, my only question now is can i make a report from this in E2 that shows the number that is in the cell at the bottom of Column D? so it shows this weeks current total?

Comment: in E2 use  `=SUMIF(A:A,YEAR(TODAY())&(WEEKNUM(TODAY(),x),C:C)`     x = 1 or 2 as above

Comment: sorry 1 ( too many  `=SUMIF(A:A,YEAR(TODAY())&WEEKNUM(TODAY(),x),C:C) `

Comment: Absolute Legend, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) with the [TODAY functio](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566) and [WEEKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Weekday-Function-05D360D7-2C3F-4691-9448-C96EA0351940) to gain a total of the current week.

```
'for a Sunday to Saturday week
=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, ">"&TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()))
'for a Monnday to Sunday week
=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, ">"&TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(), 2))
'for the previous Sunday to Saturday week
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A, ">"&TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())-7,A:A, "<="&TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()))
=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, ">"&TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(), 2)-7,A:A, "<="&TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(), 2))
```

The total for other 7 day periods can be returned with a little maths.

I've used the SUMIFS function here as the syntax changes between the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) and SUMIFS. Using SUMIFS in all cases means that you do not have to alter the syntax depending on whether you are using it one condition or multiple conditions.

Comment: Is it because it is on UK dates?

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot reproduce your difficulty, I just tried these formulas on your sample data and after adjusting for dates in column B:B I had no problem returning the sums from column C:C.